# Paragraph off the limit when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the browser is resized, paragraphs do not follow the new screen size and going off limits. I am unsure if the problem is in paragraph or in the background. I think something is wrong with height and width. Here is my site image:

[image: Check 3rd paragraph which is out of site limits]

Here is code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://oi64.tinypic.com/1zf1keu.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cont {
  width: 100%;
}
#main {
  margin-top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <div class="container" id="cont">


    <div class="row" id="main">
      <div class="  col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">

          <h2>Paragraph 1</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            </p>

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="  col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Paragraph 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            </p>

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Paragraph 3</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            </p>

        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Currently the background image contains a relative image path. Please edit it to have an absolute URL.

Comment: The distance between paragraphs doesn't automatically change when the Browser is resized.

Comment: `@Manoj Kumar`, how do you know where the user gets an image from? I think your confusing the href value in the link tag with CSS `background-image: url('relativeOk.png');`.

Comment: i try to change height body auto and i think it fixed..

Comment: You're not closing your paragraph correctly. <p>text goes here</p>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ??

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://oi64.tinypic.com/1zf1keu.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cont {
  width: 100%;
}
#main {
  margin-top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <div class="container" id="cont">


    <div class="row" id="main">
      <div class="  col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">

          <h2>Paragraph 1</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            <p>

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="  col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Paragraph 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            <p>

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Paragraph 3</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
            <p>

        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes but why is problem the cover?

Comment: @user3906418 Sorry about that mistake. can you check now? the overflow problem is solved. Just added 'background-size: cover.'